# Align and sort data java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have a program in which every time a user inputs his grades,and other data, it should be aligned correctly and according to highest and lowest scores. I made a sample code below:

```
       String[] names={"girlA","girlB","boyC"};
       String[] gradeLevel={"8th grade","10th grade" , "7th grade"};
       double[] grades={78.9,23.2,65.7};

    System.out.println("Name of Student"+ "\t" + "Grade Level"+ "\t"+ "Grades");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.println(names[i]+"\t"+ gradeLevel[i]+ "\t"+ grades[i]);
    }
```

It should look like this:

[image]

How do I align them properly without using "\t" and how do i sort the grades from highest to lowest with their names arranged accordingly with the grades?

Comment: Use objects! Parallel arrays are an antipattern that show object phobia.

Comment: Regarding the alignment of what's printed out, I would recommend looking at [formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: you should probably separate your two questions into two post. I don't think text formatting is related with sorting at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the scope of the problem, but if possible I would suggest creating an object, something like Student, containing those three fields. Then you can sort a list of students according to the grades and you will always know the name and the level of that object.
About aligning them properly if you don't want to use the tab tag you can have a look at the [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method, and do something like this:

```
String.format("%1$"+length+ "s", string);
```

This will return an string of size "length" with "string" and filling the rest up to the length with empty spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your objects using Comparable Interface or Comparator.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html